# How to use awk to print "hello" if pattern is found

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to search for a **pattern** in a tab-separated .txt-file and, if the pattern is found in a line, print the third field of that line.

I only need to find the first occurence in the line, since the pattern appears only once for sure.

Structure of .txt-file:

```
XXX01 foo target1
XXX02 bar target2
XXX03 foobar target3
```

My first idea was, to print "hello", if the pattern is found, to control, if my code works. I also included echos of the variables I pass to my bash script.

Command line call and Script:

```
$ ./script.sh file.txt foo

#!/bin/bash
file=$1
pattern=$2


awk '/"$pattern"/{print "hello"}' "$file"

echo "$file"
echo "$pattern"
```

As far as I found it for awk, to get the third field printed, I would have to substitute print "hello" with print "\$2".

But printing "hello" already does not work:

Actual output:

```
file.txt
foo
```

Desired output:

```
hello (respectively target1)
file.txt
foo
```

And I also checked for sure, that "foo" is in the file.txt

## Progress (see comments and answer please):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v p="$2"'$2=="$p"{print "hello",$3}' "$1"

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

new output:

```
awk: 1:unexpected character '.'
file.txt
foo
```

Comment: **1)** Where does `file.txt` in your output come from? How does the third record produce the output `foo`? Your input and your output don't match your logic to get there. **2)** Awk already iterates every line in the file, so there is no reason for a loop. **3)** We pass variables into an awk script using the `awk` `-v` flag. So there is a lot to change here.

Comment: file.txt comes from the echo "$file" at the pre to last line. foo comes from the last echo, "$pattern". So, the echos in the end are just for control, if my passed parameters fit. When I run the script, it works, so I think, $1 and $2 are correct?

Comment: changing the script and tags next

Comment: Ah! Gotcha. That makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: so, awk iterates through my file.txt line by line, I got that now. if I run the script as changed, I still get my actual output. Furthermore, I noticed, that my idea for getting the third field propably(?) wont work, since I get problems with $2? Or is awk working that way, that the \$2 works to address the field in the line? (got that \$2 from google-ing around)

Comment: What "pattern" are you looking for? Paisley or Herring Bone or Floral or something else? My point is - you'e NOT looking for a pattern, you're looking for either a string or a regexp and the required solution will be quite different depending on which of those it is you're looking for so [edit] your question to replace the word "pattern" with "string" or "regexp", whichever one you really mean in each context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look:

```
$ x="foo"'bar' && echo "$x"
foobar

$ x="foo" 'bar' && echo "$x"
-bash: bar: command not found
```

Your script is:

```
awk -v p="$2"'$2=="$p"{print "hello",$3}' "$1"
```

so guess what not leaving a space between `-v p="$2"` and `'$2=="$p"` is doing. Right, it's concatenating them so don't do that - add a space:

```
awk -v p="$2" '$2=="$p"{print "hello",$3}' "$1"
```

The unexpected `.` btw was the `.` in your file name `file.txt` when awk was trying to evaluate the string `file.txt` as its cript due to the concatenation consuming the actual script into the assignment to `p`.

Now to actually USE the variable `p` in the comparison you'd have to use it as a variable instead of putting it inside a string:

```
awk -v p="$2" '$2==p{print "hello",$3}' "$1"
```

The above simply answers your question about the syntax error. To actually do what you WANT would require one of these, depending on whether you want a string or regexp match and whether you want partial or full matching:

```
awk -v p="$2" '$2==p{print "hello",$3}' "$1"
awk -v p="$2" '$2~p{print "hello",$3}' "$1"
awk -v p="$2" '$2~"\\<"p"\\>"{print "hello",$3}' "$1"
```

or some other solution depending on your so far unstated requirements.

Comment: thank you for your answer. @JNevill I am not looking for people to do my work, but I want to learn and understand errors. Since I am new to programming, its not as easy as in other fields to simply google an explanation. Just applying things of others does not help, try and error, question and useful feedback do

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want something like:

```
$ ./script.sh file.txt foo

#!/bin/bash
file=$1
pattern=$2


awk -v pattern=$pattern'$2==pattern{print "hello",$3}' "$file"

echo "$file"
echo "$pattern"
```

Here we get rid of the loop since `awk` checks every record when it is fed a file. We also use the `-v` flag to pass in the `$pattern` variable into the `awk` script. Then we check that the second field `$2` is `pattern` and print `"hello"` as well as the contents of the third field `$3`.

You could change that `awk` condition to `$2~/pattern/` to truly utilize regex if you want but I suspect it will print the 1st and 3rd line as `foo` shows up in both.

If you want to check if your pattern exists in anywhere in the line then you can drop the `$2~` so it's just `'/pattern/{print "hello",$2}`.

Comment: oh damn me, @JNevill told me already, I missed the parameter handling with -v, thanks!

Comment: No worries. Once you get your head wrapped around awk it will make sense and solve a lot of problems for you.

Comment: I think, it should be: awk -v pattern="$pattern" ?

Comment: problem with my error is, whenever I saw likewise errors, the unexpected character was in the awk-command. But there is no dot? Could it come from interpolation due to false quotation, when I use " " ?

Comment: @edmorton OP has changed his question repeatedly as answers come in string us along. I answered ops original question and I'm not going to continue changing my answer slowly building ops script for them over days.